# How to create a regular expression to parse my SQL statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, regex, text-parsing

I want to extract

```
FROM codes WHERE FieldName='ContactMethod' and IsNull(Deactived,'') != 'T'
```

from

```
SELECT FieldDescription,FieldValue FROM codes WHERE FieldName='ContactMethod'
   and IsNull(Deactived,'') != 'T' order by fielddescription
```

using a regular expression.  I have a regex like this:

```
\FROM.*\order
```

which extracts

```
FROM codes WHERE FieldName='ContactMethod' and IsNull(Deactived,'') != 'T' order
```

Also, how can I get rid of the capitalization?

Comment: what "flavor" of regex are you using, in what environment? ie, Perl, .NET, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here would probably be to capture the part you actually want with parens:

```
(FROM.*) order
```

This would greedily match until the last `order`, if you want only until the first occurrence, match lazily:

```
(FROM.*?) order
```

Comment: This one works but I don't want the word "Order" i want everything starting from the word "FROM" till the word "order" excluding the word "Order" also i want it case insensitive.

Comment: isn't that what the (parentheses) are for?

Comment: It still gives me " FROM codes WHERE FieldName='ContactMethod' and IsNull(Deactived,'') != 'T' order"

Comment: The first match (the stuff in brackets) will be the part without order.  Read up about RegEx matches.

Comment: To not have order show up in the match, do this "(FROM.*)(?=order)"

Comment: Thanks all who took time to answer my question!

Comment: FYI: You can use the expression that Fabian gives and say Regex.Match("(FROM.*) order").Groups[1].Value

Comment: I'd also recommend using ` (FROM .*) ORDER BY ` (note spaces around FROM and inclusion of "BY ") for a little extra robustness, in case the table's name includes "from" or the FROM clause contains " order".

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Fabian Steeg's answer

```
 Dim regex As Regex = New Regex( _
          "(FROM.*?) ORDER", _
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase _
        Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant _
        Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace _
        Or RegexOptions.Compiled _
        )

    Dim ms As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(InputText)
```

where InputText is of course your SQL query string.

ms(1) should hold the parentheses match

Answer (score 0):

If it comes down to it you can ignore capitalization by doing (F|f)(R|r)(O|o)(M|m).

Comment: yup..that solves the case sensitive issue. I am still getting the word "Order" which i don't want. I am using (from|FROM.*)order|ORDER

Comment: Nearly all regex flavors support a case-insensitivity flag.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive tools like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) ($40) or [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) (free) would really help you to design and debug regular expressions for most platforms.